# Are Doctrine-generated association properties always of type ArrayCollection?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am currently trying to filter a Doctrine-generated association property by using `Criteria` as described in the Doctrine manual: [Filtering Collections](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

Here is some sample code: A person who owns several cars. For the sake of simplicity we save the date when the person bought and sold the car in the car entity instead of creating an association entity.

```
class Car
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="bought", type="date")
     */
    private $bought;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="sold", type="date")
     */
    private $sold;
}

class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Car", mappedBy="owner")
     */
    private $cars;

    public function __construct
    {
        $this->cars = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get cars
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }

    public function getCarsOwnedAtDate(\DateTime $date)
    {
        $allCars = $this->getCars();

        $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(
            Criteria::expr()->andX(
                Criteria::expr()->lte("bought", $date),
                Criteria::expr()->gte("sold", $date)
            )
        );

        return $allCars->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```

The documentation for `getCars` says that it returns a `Collection`. Note that this documentation is auto-generated by Doctrine.

So when I call `matching` on `Collection` in my `getCarsOwnedAtDate` method my IDE issues a warning that `Collection` does not have a `matching` method. Turns out, it is right.

The object returned by `getCars` is an `ArrayCollection` and has a `matching` method so the code runs fine.

My question is: Can I rely on the fact that methods auto-generated by Doctrine will always return an `ArrayCollection`? Or will the above code fail in a certain case? If it does always return `ArrayCollection`, then why does the PhpDoc comment not mention this class explicitly?

Comment: If you are using LAZY collections (default in Doctrine2) - yes, the're ArrayCollections. If you're using EXTRA_LAZY they're PersistentCollections (they have "matching" method too). But interface Collection from auto-generated doc doesn't have a matching method. Generated doc is valid because ArrayCollection and PersistentCollection implements Collection interface (and your field is a Collection right?). But remember, it's only generated code (which should be generic), you can change it to fit your implementation.

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski So is there any configuration in which my collection does not contain a `matching` method? I.e. is it possible that I might chagne the configuration later on and my code breaks for non-obvious reasons?

Comment: It's just PHPDoc with @return, it not implies any changes how code works. It's only for you and your IDE :)

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski Yes, I am aware of that. However, I need to know what the returned object's type is so I can rely on the object having certain methods. If I rely on the fact that there is a `matching` method but it is in reality simply a coincidence that it is there, then I am using undocumented features and might run into problems e.g. when changing the configuration.

Comment: So assume that the method which returns LAZY or EXTRA LAZY collection returns not a Collection interface but ArrayCollection or PersistentCollection. During refactor you should think about it. I don't see any other solution. PHP is dymamically typed which is bless and curse in the same time.